# Hide everything on dom until everything is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to change the content of a div on the page but the page has a lot of things to load and on slower computers there is a flicker where you can see the div changing (changing through jquery btw). Is there anyway that everything can be hidden and display it all at including the changes I made using jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue with my web application.. This is what I did

Hide body in HTML

`<body style="display:none">`

And write this script :

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $("body").fadeIn(100);
});
```

OR this script

```
$(window).load(function () {
   $("body").fadeIn(100);
}
```

This creates beautiful effect and shows the page ONLY after everything is fully loaded..

Comment: if the div is flickery with jQuery, the `fadeIn(100)` may also be flickery

Comment: Nope.. The div will be hidden until and unless the whole markup and scripts are loaded.. So the flickering and everything will be hidden behind for all the "load" time.. :-)

Comment: Looks great! Only problem I am having now is if I go to a new page it sets the body to display none and I have to refresh the page to get it to load. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Include the script I have given in some script file (e.g. custom.js) and include it in every page that you load.. try if that works

Comment: I am making the changes through Greasemonkey so I can't do that.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. Instead of using a fadeIn I just set the display to block on load. Works perfectly now.

Comment: ^ Awesome. glad it worked.. I added fadeIn just for some beautification.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could do something like

```
<head>
     <style>
         body{
            display:none;
         }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
   flickery <div></div>s go here
</body>`
```

And your script

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(document.body).css("display","block"); //shows it when all the elements are ready for   presentation
});
```

Comment: you should hide body using CSS rule instead. Here you are waiting the DOM to be ready before hiding body

Comment: Agree with the above comment.. We shall not wait for DOM to be loaded.. Hide body in markup itself